# encode multiple jpg files in a folder as base 64 in python

Tags: python

How do I encode multiple jpeg files in a folder as base 64. Currently my code can encode one file. However I would like this to encode all the jpeg files in a folder path.

```
with open("path\\A.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

extract_ocr_words(encoded_string)

In the above path there'll be multiple jpeg files such as

```
A.jpg
B.jpg
C.jpg
```

the final output should combine all the images in the folder and extract text and show as list in the final command

```
extract_ocr_words(encoded_string)

['ABC', 'LKM', 'GHI', 'TLI', 'CLI']
```

Comment: Check out the `glob` module to loop through file names. e.g. `for filename in glob.glob("path\\*.jpg")`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'm relatively new to python. Could you please let me know how this could be incorparted in to the code that I have provided? thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Just iterate over files in the folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the files inside the folder. You can use `os` library ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)):

```
import os

words = []
directory = 'path/to/your/pictures'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), "rb") as image_file:
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
            words.extend(extract_ocr_Words(encoded_string))
    else:
        continue
print('Words from all files')
print(words)
```

Also you can use `os.path.join()` ([link to function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)) function which concatenate two parts of path. It will works on Windows and Unix system. It is better than escaping of `\`. Then it is up to you what do you want to do with the encoded images.

You can still shorten your code by using `glob` package.
The functionality can be achieved as follows:

```
import glob

words = []
for f_name in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    with open(f_name,"rb") as image_file:
         encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
         words = extract_ocr_Words(encoded_string)
         words.extend(extract_ocr_Words(encoded_string))
    else:
        continue
print('Words from all files')
print(words)
```